# Drop down list not displaying

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I am populating my drop downs using mysql and php.  I have the contents stored in a table.  I call them at the head of a page where they are needed an then insert the results where needed.  I am doing it this way so the end user can update their own drop down list from  a UI.  It also saves me having to type the bloody things over and over.  I have it done alread for some drop down number list.  Usual thing, select a number etc.  Works a treat.  This new one is for words. I know the sql is getting the data from the db and the drop down does actually drop down but you cant see anything on the page. View page source shows me that the data is in the page.  Its just seeable. The code for embedding into the page is exactly the same as the numbered drop downs. Im stumped.  I should point out that using code to populate the drop downs was taught to me by someone in this group. For which I am very grateful.

```
//POPULATE RISK AREA
$sql = "SELECT  riskArea FROM tblriskarea ORDER BY riskArea ASC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if (!$conn->query($sql)) {
    echo "query failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}

$areaOptions = "";
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $areaOptions .= '<option value="'.   $row['riskArea'].'">';
}
```

and the code to show it in the table is thus:

```
<select name="riskarea" style="width:100px" ><?php echo "$areaOptions";   ?></select></td>
```

but I get nothing. Anything leaping out at you?

Comment: You're not showing the text so the option values are not visible in select dropdown. Required change is `$areaOptions .= '<option value="'.   $row['riskArea'].'">';` this should be like this `$areaOptions .= '<option value="'.   $row['riskArea'].'">.'$row['riskArea']'.</option>';`

Comment: @Haridarshan post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two error in your code

1)Your connection variable is `$conn` not `$mysqli`
SO you can check your query error using

```
if (!$conn->query($sql)) {
echo "query failed: (" . $conn->errno . ") " . $conn->error;
}
```

2) Forget to write text and close the option in dropdown. It would be

```
$areaOptions = "";
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $areaOptions .= '<option value="' . $row['riskArea'] . '">"' . $row['riskArea'] . '"</option>';
}
```

Comment: thanks for that. Interestingly on the error checking  I have the correct on elsewhere.  Cut and paste will get you every time.

Comment: supplementary question.  I have now put the code for that in a config file and dump the output to a session variable so now put that variable on the pages as required.  The problem I am having is that on some of the pages I pull data to populate the forms so that the end user can modify them if needed.  When I populate the drop downs using this method I cant seem to get the already entered data to show AS WELL as the dynamic drop down.  Might be impossible but would be nice.

Comment: I answered this question myself.  I make them into datalists and use placeholders to display the entry pulled from the databse.

Answer (score 3):

You have not put html closing tag `</option>`. Use the following code:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $areaOptions .= '<option value="' . $row['riskArea'] . '">"' . $row['riskArea'] . '"</option>';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to complete the option tag:

```
$areaOptions = "";
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $areaOptions .= '<option value="'.$row['riskArea'].'">'.$row['riskArea'].'</option>';
}
```

In select tag:

```
<select name="riskarea" style="width:100px" ><?php echo $areaOptions;   ?></select></td>
```

Answer (score 2):

Required Changes:

1) `<option>` text is not showing.

2) `<option>` is not closing.

**Corrected Code:**

```
//POPULATE RISK AREA
$sql = "SELECT  riskArea FROM tblriskarea ORDER BY riskArea ASC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if (!$conn->query($sql)) {
    echo "query failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}
$areaOptions = "";
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $areaOptions .= '<option value="'.   $row['riskArea'].'">' . $row['riskArea'] . '</option>';
}
```

Comment: Correct but check the connection variable. It is `$conn` not `$mysqli`

Answer (score 1):

You're not showing the text so the option values are not visible in select dropdown.

```
$areaOptions .= '<option value="'. $row['riskArea'].'">';
```

this should be like this

```
$areaOptions .= '<option value="'. $row['riskArea'].'">.'$row['riskArea']'.</option>';
```